Use MSG_ZEROCOPY in combination with mmap and custom kernel module
I have an embedded Linux device with 2GB RAM. In my device tree and kernel boot arguments, I configured the system to use just the lower 1GB of RAM.
As the device is an intelFPGA SoC, the upper area of the RAM is written from the FPGA fabric.
With a custom Linux device driver, I map the upper are to user space with the function remap_pfn_range. (My full mmap driver function is shown bellow).
This works as expected. But now, I try to use the zero-copy infrastructure to send the data over TCP to another PC. With the current implementation, I use the write function without zero-copy and the cost of high CPU usage.
When I tried to use the send function with the MSG_ZEROCOPY flag, the user space application doesn't work anymore and send returns error code 14, Bad Address.
Now I try to update my Linux kernel, but I'm not sure which kind of kernel function I have to use? I'm using Kernel 6.6.
static int my_mmap(struct file* filp, struct vm_area_struct* vma)
{
    struct mem_dev *hm = (struct mem_dev *)filp->private_data;

    unsigned long off = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
    unsigned long pfn = (hm->offset + off) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
    unsigned long vsize = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long psize = hm->size - off;

    printk("my_mmap called.\n");

    if (vsize > psize) {
        printk("my_mmap out of region...\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    printk("my_mmap remap_pfn_range, virt 0x%lx, phys 0x%lx\n",
                vma->vm_start, pfn);
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, 
                vma->vm_start, 
                pfn,
                vsize,
                vma->vm_page_prot)) {
        printk("my_mmap remap_pfn_range failed.\n");
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    vma->vm_ops = &simple_remap_vm_ops;
    simple_vma_open(vma);
    return 0;
}

